# Qt signal slot with threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have a problem with signal/slots in a QThread class. My design looks like this:

```
class Manager : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Manager(QObject* parent) : QObject(parent) {
        Thread thread* = new Thread(this);
        connect(this, SIGNAL(testsignal()), thread, SLOT(test()));
        thread->start();

        ...

        emit testsignal();
    }
signals:
    void testsignal();
};

class Thread : public QThread {
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void test() {
        qDebug() << "TEST";
    }
private:
    void run() {}
};
```

The signal never reaches my test() method. Can someone help? Thanks.

Comment: `Thread::test()` is not defined as a slot.

Comment: Sorry. It was a typo.

Comment: `Thread thread*` another typo? Your code works for me now.

Comment: Why do you have an empty `run()` method in your `Thread`? What for? There's already a perfectly good implementation of `run()` that you simply have to leave alone. Similarly, you should not derive from `QThread`. Put your `test()` slot into a `QObject`-derived class that's **not** a thread.

Comment: Just in passing - don't subclass `QThread`; instead, create a `QThread`, move the appropriate objects to it, then start its event loop.  See [How To Really, Truly Use QThreads](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/) by Maya Posch for good advice.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that [sending signals across threads](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads) results in queuing the signal into the target thread's event queue (a queued connection). If that thread never processes events, it'll never get the signal.

Also, [according to the `QThread::run` documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qthread.html#run):

> Returning from this method will end the execution of the thread.

In other words, having an empty `run` method results in instant termination of the thread, so you're sending a signal to a dead thread.

Comment: Ok. I added a infinte loop to my run method: `while (true) {}` and nothing changed. I never receive a signal.

Comment: @adapto because you need to start the *event* loop easiest way to do that is to call `this->exec()` (or don't re-implement run in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

Signals sent to a QThread object will go to the thread of the parent object. In this case to the **same thread that created it**.

To have a object live on another thread you should move it to that thread:

```
class Manager : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Manager(QObject* parent) : QObject(parent) {
        Thread thread* = new QThread(this);
        Receiver* rec = new Receiver(); //no parent
        connect(this, SIGNAL(testsignal()), rec, SLOT(test()));
        connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), rec, SLOT(deleteLater()));
        rec->moveToThread(thread);
        thread->start();

        ...

        emit testsignal();
    }
signals:
    void testsignal();
};

class Receiver: public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void test() {
        qDebug() << "TEST";
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and it didn't work. I added `connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), mFetchTilesThread, SLOT(run()));` and put my `run()` method to `public slot`. And this method is called properly.